# Help to tabular. How to set different sizes of cell in tabular enviroment?

Tags: tables

I´m sorry by English mistakes.
I´m looking for how to set of different sizes of cells in tabular enviroment, like picture (I would like the table to span the entire page width). How can I do this?

I´m using these packages

```
\documentclass[a4paper,brazil, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\geometry{a4paper,
    top=1.5cm,  
    bottom=1.5cm,   
    left=1.5cm,
    right=1.5cm,
}


  \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{{Question}} & \multirow{2}{*}{a} & \multirow{2}{*}{b} & \multirow{2}{*}{c} & \multirow{2}{*}{d} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Scores} \\ 
    \cmidrule{6-7}
     &  &  &  &  & Individual & Team \\ 
    \midrule 
    1 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    2 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    3 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    4 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    5 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    6 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    7 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    8 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    9 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    10 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Total} &  &  \\ 
    \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular} 
    \end{document}
```

Thanks for everyone.

[image]

Comment: Could you please show what you have tried so far. Please also state what the problematic part is. Is it the colors, the alignment, the headers of the last two columns...?

Comment: I have been put above. Unfortunately this is my first "big table"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of the `tabularx` package you can ensure that the table is as wide as the textwidth. I have declared a new, centered column type for this. With `xcolor` and the `table` option the `rowcolor` and `columncolor` commands can be used. With `>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}` you can change the width of the `C` type columns. (Make sure that the sum of the values is equal to the number of `C` type columns used (e.g. 1.5+1.5+0.75+0.25=4 for 4 columns).

Lastly, I'd not recommend using the lines from the `booktabs` package in combination with vertical lines (as you did in your MWE). You might have noticed the small gaps in the vertical lines that are due to the fact that the booktabs lines are designed to be used in tables without vertical lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hhline}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}

\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\columncolor{lightgray}}c
                             |>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}C
                             |>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}C
                             |>{\hsize=.75\hsize}C
                             |>{\hsize=.25\hsize}C
                             |c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray}
& & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Scores}\\ \hhline{*5{>{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}}-}*{2}{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-}}
\rowcolor{lightgray}
\multirow{-2.2}{*}{Question} & \multirow{-2.2}{*}{a)} & \multirow{-2.2}{*}{b)} & \multirow{-2.2}{*}{c)} & \multirow{-2.2}{*}{d)} & Individual & Team \\
\hline
1. & & & & & & \\
\hline
2. & & & & & & \\
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray}
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{TOTAL} & & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

---

If you wish to stick to the `booktabs` lines, I'd suggest a layout without vertical lines, with fewer horizontal lines and without color:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lCCCCcc}
\toprule
& & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Scores}\\ \cmidrule{6-7}
\multirow{-2.2}{*}{Question} & \multirow{-2.2}{*}{a)} & \multirow{-2.2}{*}{b)} & \multirow{-2.2}{*}{c)} & \multirow{-2.2}{*}{d)} & Individual & Team \\
\midrule
1. & & & & & & \\
2. & & & & & & \\
\cmidrule{1-5}
\multicolumn{5}{l}{TOTAL} & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don´t know why, but your first set doesn´t work for me. 
But thanks for your help. 
I´m trying to fix here.

Comment: @Moura: Do you get any error messages or just not the shwon output?

Comment: Your MWE works, but if you realize your picture above, if you notice, you will see that some lines disappear. Try again using 10 itens, please.

Comment: @Moura: The disapprearing vertical line between d) and Scores is definitely a viewer issue. THe line will appear if you zoom in. This issue of disappearing lines in combination with colored cells is well known.

Comment: @Moura: Regarding the missing short horizontal line below Sources: This was a mistake. I have edited my anser to also include this line.

Comment: I´m so sorry, but it didn´t work for me. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93984/discussion-between-moura-and-leandriis).

Answer (score 2):

Use `tabularx` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,brazil, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\geometry{a4paper,
    top=1.5cm,  
    bottom=1.5cm,   
    left=1.5cm,
    right=1.5cm,
}
\usepackage{tabularx}


  \begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{{Question}} & \multirow{2}{*}{a} & \multirow{2}{*}{b} & \multirow{2}{*}{c} & \multirow{2}{*}{d} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Scores} \\ 
    \cmidrule{6-7}
     &  &  &  &  & Individual & Team \\ 
    \midrule 
    1 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    2 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    3 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    4 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    5 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    6 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    7 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    8 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    9 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    10 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \midrule  
    \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Total} &  &  \\ 
    \bottomrule 
    \end{tabularx} 
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

**1. Requested layout**

If you want to try a different solution, in particular if you build a class or template, here is a solution using [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cals, calc}

\newlength{\bcw}
\thispagestyle{empty}

% Shortcuts
\let\nc=\nullcell
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}

\setlength{\bcw}{((\columnwidth / 30))} %  basic column width is half the width of narrowest column

\noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{2pt}\smallskip % checking that the tabular do not extend into the margin

\begin{calstable}
\makeatletter
\colwidths{{3.5\bcw}{5.5\bcw}{5.5\bcw}{4\bcw}{3.5\bcw}{5.5\bcw}{2.5\bcw}{0pt}} % Sum should be 30
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}

%
\brow
    \def\cals@bgcolor{lightgray} % Color command is in effect until reset
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\textbf{Scores}}
    \cell{}
\erow
%
\brow
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{\vfil \textbf{Question}} % Alignment command works until reset by a `\alignL` or `\alignR`
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil a)}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil b)}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil c)}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil d)}
    \cell{Individual}
    \cell{Team}
    \cell{}
\erow
%
\brow
    \cell{1.}
    \def\cals@bgcolor{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%
\brow
    \def\cals@bgcolor{lightgray}
    \cell{2.}
    \def\cals@bgcolor{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%
\brow
    \def\cals@bgcolor{lightgray}
    \cell{3.}
    \def\cals@bgcolor{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%
\brow
    \def\cals@bgcolor{lightgray}
    \cell{4.}
    \def\cals@bgcolor{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%
\brow
    \def\cals@bgcolor{lightgray}
    \cell{5.}
    \def\cals@bgcolor{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%
\brow
    \def\cals@bgcolor{lightgray}
    \cell{6.}
    \def\cals@bgcolor{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%
\brow
    \def\cals@bgcolor{lightgray}
    \cell{7.}
    \def\cals@bgcolor{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%
\brow
    \def\cals@bgcolor{lightgray}
    \cell{8.}
    \def\cals@bgcolor{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%
\brow
    \def\cals@bgcolor{lightgray}
    \cell{9.}
    \def\cals@bgcolor{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%
\brow
    \def\cals@bgcolor{lightgray}
    \cell{10.}
    \def\cals@bgcolor{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%
\brow
    \def\cals@bgcolor{lightgray}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignR\sc{\textbf{TOTAL}}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \def\cals@bgcolor{}
\erow
\makeatother
\end{calstable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**2.‘booktabs’ version**

Here is my attempt to code a ‘booktabs’-version of the tabular:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{cals, calc}
\newlength{\bcw}
\thispagestyle{empty}

% Shortcuts
\let\nc=\nullcell
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}

\setlength{\bcw}{((\columnwidth / 30))} %  basic column width is half the width of narrowest column

\noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{2pt}\bigskip % checking that the tabular do not extend into the margin

\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{1.25\bcw}{2.75\bcw}{5\bcw}{5\bcw}{4\bcw}{4\bcw}{5\bcw}{3\bcw}} % Sum should be 30
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.8pt}
\def\cals@framecs@width{0pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0pt}
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}

%
\setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
\thead{\bfseries\selectfont%
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \nc{lt}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \nc{rt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{ltb}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{Scores}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}    
\erow
%
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \nc{lb}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \nc{rb}\alignL\sc{\vfil Question} % Alignment command works until reset by a `\alignL` or `\alignR`
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{\vfil a)}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil b)}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil c)}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil d)}
    \cell{Individual}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{Team}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}    
\erow
\mdseries}
%
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{1.}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}    
\erow
%
\brow
    \def\cals@rs@width{0pt}
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{2.}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}    
\erow
%
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{3.}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}    
\erow
%
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{4.}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}    
\erow
%
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{5.}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}    
\erow
%
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{6.}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}    
\erow
%
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{7.}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}    
\erow
%
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{8.}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}    
\erow
%
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{9.}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}    
\erow
%
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{10.}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}    
\erow
%
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\textbf{TOTAL}}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \cell{}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cell{}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}    
    \def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}
\erow\makeatother
\end{calstable}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]